# Buttons disappear on hover in IE11

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason when viewing my website www.webfounded.com in Internet Explorer all of my bootstrap buttons disappear on hover! It is very frustrating and I cannot find a solution anywhere. I even have the CSS classes added for multiple browser compatibility and even tried deleting the hover/active classes all together! I don't need hover effects for IE, just need it so they don't disappear. Thanks in advance for any help.

```
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
       -o-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.btn:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;
  -khtml-opacity: .92;
  -moz-opacity: .92;
  -ms-filter: ”alpha(opacity=92)”;
  filter: alpha(opacity=92);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=0.5);
  opacity: .92;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.btn:active,
.btn.active {
  background-image: none;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
          box-shadow: inset 0 3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
}
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled],
fieldset[disabled] .btn {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
          box-shadow: none;
  opacity: .65;
}
```

Comment: can you show us some HTML as well?

Comment: Do you know if a later version of IE11 has fixed this problem?  I remember having similar issues in the past but cannot reproduce the problem now.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `opacity` from `.btn:hover, .btn:focus`

```
.btn:hover,
.btn:focus {
  color: #fff;     
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

You have to remove this from your `bootstrap.min.css` too.

Hope this will help

Comment: Removing values from external css files is never good practice.
Instead include a new file overriding required values.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had display: inline-block; but by changing to display: block; it resolved the issue. Thanks for the help though.